# get index of parent, select same index from another div

Tags: jquery, indexing

On a click, I'm trying to get the index of the parent of the item clicked. Then, I want to choose that same index from another div.

I can see how this works:

```
var myIndex = $(this).parent().index();
```

but I'm a little confused as to then use that index value/position to say "okay, now look over here in this container and choose a div at that same index value" as this isn't working:

```
$('#allFishAnswers:eq(myIndex)')...
```

I've set up a ridiculous HTML that will show two columns. questions and answers. The source order of each is important as that's the basic logic behind attributing question 1 with answer 1. However, by using the index of each, it can be dynamic. Just the bare bones to hopefully visualize better:

http://jsfiddle.net/thumbslinger/KbL68/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var myIndex = $(this).parent().index();
$('#allFishAnswers div').eq(myIndex).show(); // <-- whatever
```